# Facebook-Like social plugins all show the same counts on all pages

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

I have a website that is registered as an app in Facebook. The website has a main page with many sub pages. Each of the pages has their own Like buttons. However, each of the pages show the same Like counts. All the pages show the same count as the website.

I have the following in my page(s) markup:

```
<meta property="og:description" content="Get the latest dates, events and happenings from the Dutch Hill PTA School Calendar." />
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="481535935203351" />
<meta property="og:title" content="School Calendar | Dutch Hill PTA" />
<meta property="og:type" content="article" />
<meta property="og:url" content="http://www.dutchhillpta.com/about/SchoolCalendar.aspx" />
<meta property="og:image" content="http://www.dutchhillpta.com/images/DutchHillPTA.jpg" />
<meta property="og:site_name" content="School Calendar | Dutch Hill PTA" />
<meta property="og:description" content="Get the latest dates, events and happenings from the Dutch Hill PTA School Calendar." />
<meta property="fb:admins" content="xxxxxxxxxxxx" />
```

This is what the facebook like button look like:

```
<div class="fb-like" data-href="http://www.dutchhillpta.com/about/SchoolCalendar.aspx" data-width="450" data-colorscheme="light" data-layout="standard" data-action="like" data-show-faces="true" data-send="true"></div>
```

I have tried to make sure that the data-href is unique for each page on the website. However that does not seem to matter as it only shows the counts for the main page.

Any idea? Thanks!

Comment: Have you set the same `og:url` for all of your pages by any chance? That value is what Facebook ties the likes to, so it has to be different for all the pages that you want to like individually.

Comment: I checked that. The data-href and og:url are unique for all pages on the site. On the same page, the data-href and the og:url are the same.

Comment: Put your URLs through the debug tool, and see if it says everything’s alright: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug Have a look at the “Canoncial URL” in particular, that’s the URL Facebook uses to identify the objects and associate the comments with.

Comment: The canonical url in the debug site shows up properly and the pages get scraped properly. However, I do get random errors stating it cannot identify the og:image or the og:description tags but they still show up in the meta tags it identified. I refresh and everything works.

Answer (score 1):

If the html5 not working you could try iframe method like this :

```
<iframe src="//www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href= your unique link &amp;width=450&amp;height=35&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;layout=standard&amp;action=like&amp;show_faces=false&amp;send=false" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:450px; height:35px;" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>
```

or create your own here :

```
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/like-button/
```

If it does not work the problem could be the facebook connection.